# Salesforce DR error

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity

[image: SF DR error]

Hey I'm getting this DR error while on the Omni-script. this is happening after deactivating and activating the Omni-Script.

I'm trying to figure out the root cause of the issue, but it does not look familiar to me.
Any idea?